# How to convert all the strings in a list of a list to floats

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I've used this code to open a excel file, to create lists of each line of the excel file:

```
import csv
with open("csvfile.csv", "rb") as f:
    lines = list(csv.reader(f))

>>> lines
[['0', '23.345', '-122.456'], ['1', '12.546', '-118.987'] ['2', '67.435', '-104.112']]
```

I do want to keep the lists of each line of the excel file in a bigger list, but I want each element to be floats rather than strings. What alteration would I have to make?

i.e  `[[0, 23.345, -122.456], [1, 12.546, -118.987], [2, 67.435, -104.112]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use nested *list comprehension* on your list of lists as:

```
>>> my_list = [['0', '23.345', '-122.456'], ['1', '12.546', '-118.987'], ['2', '67.435', '-104.112']]

>>> [[float(i) for i in sub_list] for sub_list in my_list]
[[0.0, 23.345, -122.456], [1.0, 12.546, -118.987], [2.0, 67.435, -104.112]]
```

Comment: You can replace the inner list comprehension with a map statement. `[list(map(float, sub_list)) for sub_list in my_list]`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid One should ignore map whenever it is possible to do so. *list comprehension* is more efficient than `map`. In fact, even Guido was not a fan of `map()`

Comment: @burhankhalid you don't need the list outside map.

Comment: In Python 3 you do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` in a list-comprehension while reading the file.

```
import csv

with open("csvfile.csv", "rb") as f:
    lines = [map(float, line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

Saves you creating a list twice (reading, converting)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[map(float, sub_list) for sub_list in my_list]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [map(float, sub_list) for sub_list in my_list]
[[0.0, 23.345, -122.456], [1.0, 12.546, -118.987], [2.0, 67.435, -104.112]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
lines = list(csv.reader(f))
```

into:

```
lines = [[float(x) for x in line] for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

i.e.:

```
import csv
    with open("csvfile.csv", "rb") as f:
        lines =  [[float(x) for x in line] for line in csv.reader(f)]
```